# Trigger remote Jenkins job on GCE VM

Tags: jenkins, google-compute-engine, ssh-tunnel

I am currently running Jenkins on a GCE VM. As a build step, I want to trigger a Jenkins job on another VM in the same project. The problem is, HTTP and HTTPS access to the VMs is disabled, and I cannot use `curl` to trigger it remotely. An SSH tunnel remains the only option. But SSH onto a VM requires a google_compute_engine private key file, which helps you log in to a particular user..I was confused about how to use this file for the Jenkins user, which does not have a separate shell and was hoping for some advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to apply the default firewall rules to allow HTTP and HTTPS traffic to the instance by setting the **Allow HTTP traffic** and **Allow HTTPS traffic** checkboxs on in its detailed view at Developers Console, or adding the **http-server** and **https-server** tags manually by using gcloud command: "

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags INSTANCE --tags http-server https-server".
```

Setting up an SSH tunnel to Jenkins port of service is a possibility and it doesn't require using google_compute_engine key necessarily. You can configure and additional key and copy the public part for that key into Jenkins user's authorized_keys file directly, as you would with any other server. See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#sshkeys) for more details.  If you use a custom SSH key, remember to specify the related private key when setting up the tunnel.

Another more straight-forward option would be creating new firewall rules for Jenkins ports and applying them to the Jenkins instance.